# How to connect a virtual machine from one local network to a computer from another local network via the Internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, vpn, internet

There is a laptop with Windows 10, VirtualBox is installed on it. The laptop has a "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" network adapter through which it communicates with the Ubuntu virtual machine via a local virtual network. VLAN uses static addresses.

The laptop is connected via Wi-fi to the Internet via a router. Dynamic addresses are used between the laptop and the router on the network.

There is a computer with Windows 10, it is connected via Wi-fi to the Internet through a router. Dynamic addresses are used on the network between the computer and the router. The router has a permanent Internet address.

This computer is also connected via Ethernet to the Ubuntu computer. This is a point-to-point connection and uses static addresses.

How can I SSH from an Ubuntu virtual machine to an Ubuntu computer on different LANs over the Internet?

Comment: if you wish to reach another LAN over the internet, you need a tunneling technology like a VPN or SSH. That said, both will require major changes in your network configuration to function properly.

Comment: This article  https://www.howtogeek.com/311287/how-to-connect-to-an-ssh-server-from-windows-macos-or-linux/  might assist you.